# Need to draw an blur lines using xml

Tags: java, android, xml

Need to draw an blur lines using xml not with an image or bitmap.

[image]

// in xml I am just drawing a line.

how to make that as an blur edges

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/blur_divider_line"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
/>
```

[here they](http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2012/05/create-blur-edge-on-bitmap-using.html) are using blur effect in bitmap using BlurMaskFilter.

Answer (score 3):

Use a gradient whose start and end color is same whereas middle color will be solid. This will create a shadow effect.

```
                 <gradient 
                    android:angle="270" 
                    android:startColor="#0fff"
                    android:centerColor="#000"                        
                    android:endColor="#0fff" 
                    android:type="linear" />
```

Note that the start and end color should have 100% transparency.